# Creating a Circle of Known Area

Tags: r, geometry, buffer, r-sf

I want to create a circle of area 100 as an sf object. I thought st_buffer() would do it, but the area is
slightly less than 100.

```
pt.df   <- data.frame(pt = 1, x = 20, y = 20)
pt.sf   <- st_as_sf(pt.df, coords = c("x", "y")) 
circle1 <- st_buffer(pt.sf, dist = sqrt(100 / pi))
st_area(circle1)  # 99.95431 on my PC
```

I can use a fudge factor to multiply the radius and I get what I want.

```
fudge    <- sqrt( 100 / st_area(circle1) )
circle2  <- st_buffer(pt.sf, dist = fudge * sqrt(100 / pi))
st_area(circle2)  # 100
```

But it seems silly to use a fudge factor.

Is there a way to create a circle of known area within the sf package without
a fudge factor in st_buffer ?

Comment: Does an error of 0.05% really matter ? Why ?

Comment: pi is an irrational number.  An analytically exact area of 100 is impossible.  The calculated result is limited by the precision of pi used in the calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `st_buffer` works internally with polygons, not with circles. Increasing the `nQuadSegs` argument (default=30) allows you to use a better approximation to a circle, at the cost of memory and computation time (don't know if this is important to you):

```
library(sf)
pt.df   <- data.frame(pt = 1, x = 20, y = 20)
pt.sf   <- st_as_sf(pt.df, coords = c("x", "y")) 
get_area <- function(nq) {
  circle1 <- st_buffer(pt.sf, dist = sqrt(100 / pi), nQuadSegs=nq)
  st_area(circle1)
}
sapply(c(30,100,300,1000), get_area)
## [1] 99.95431 99.99589 99.99954 99.99996
```

If you really want an area of *exactly* 100, then the 'fudge' that your question (and @AdamTrevisan's answer) suggest is the way to go (as increasing the number of segments to a million still only gets you to an area of 99.99999999997200461621). To be *really* clever, you might be able to use the formula for the [area of an inscribed polygon](https://www.efunda.com/math/areas/polygoninscribedgen.cfm) to come up with a correction factor ...

Answer (score 3):

It's a float precision issue calculating the radius with a truncated form of pi. This will result in a circle that is slightly less than what your desired output is. You can see that pi can only be stored to machine precision:

```
.Machine$double.eps
# 2.22044604925031e-16

pi
# 3.14159265358979
```

If you want to correct it, you can use a linear correction on the area that you want. Note that this is still an approximation, but it should get you much closer to your desired result.

```
radius <- function(area){
    A <- area + (area * 0.000457099999999997)
    return(sqrt(A / pi))
}

system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf") %>% 
        st_read() %>% 
        st_centroid() %>% 
        st_transform(st_crs(5070)) %>% 
        st_buffer(radius(100)) %>%
        st_area()
```